# How to add multiple table relationship in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have following tables and building query with Laravel relationship. In my panel, once the user logged I am getting user details & user business details but now I don't know how to get business types details too.

### User Table:

```
id | business_id | username | email          | password
1    1             john632    john@gmail.com   *******
```

### Users Business Table

```
id | user_id | business_type_id | business_name
1    1         2                  Fortune
```

### Business Types Table

```
id | business_type_name | description
1    Hotel                Lorem Ipsum
2    Movie                Lorem Ipsum
```

### Models:

**User**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Zizaco\Entrust\Traits\EntrustUserTrait;
use App\Notifications\ResetPassword as ResetPasswordNotification;
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Webpatser\Uuid\Uuid;
use App\RoleUser;
use App\UsersBusiness;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    use EntrustUserTrait;
    use HasApiTokens;
    use SoftDeletes, EntrustUserTrait {
        SoftDeletes::restore as sfRestore;
        EntrustUserTrait::restore as euRestore;
    }

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'business_id', 'username', 'email'
    ];

    public function usersBusiness()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\UsersBusiness', 'business_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

**UsersBusiness**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class UsersBusiness extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'tbl_users_business';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id', 'business_type_id', 'business_name'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [

    ];

    /**
     * Dates to be treated as Carbon instances
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public $dates = [
        'deleted_at'
    ];
}
```

**BusinessTypes**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class BusinessTypes extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'tbl_master_business_types';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'business_type_name', 'description'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [

    ];

    /**
     * Dates to be treated as Carbon instances
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public $dates = [
        'deleted_at'
    ];
}
```

### Code:

```
$user = Auth::user();
$data['data'] = $user->load(['usersBusiness'] => function ($query) {
    $query->select(["id", "user_id", "business_name"])->get();
}]);
```

I am getting below response data:

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": 1,
        "business_id": 1,
        "username": "john632",
        "email": "john632@gmail.com",
        "password": "john632",
        "users_business": {
            "id": 1,
            "user_id": 4,
            "business_type_id": 3,
            "business_name": "Honest"
        },
        "business_types": null
    },
    "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6Ijk4YTQ5OTBmOGQxOWQ5NTg1OGFlZWU1MDY0NTBiY2Y2OWJmOWQ3NzFhZjRmN2RmMzBmMWRkZWNmNWY4OTAzM2UyNmI2MzE3MTY3MDMxOTk4In0.eyJhdWQiOiIxIiwianRpIjoiOThhNDk5MGY4ZDE5ZDk1ODU4YWVlZTUwNjQ1MGJjZjY5YmY5ZDc3MWFmNGY3ZGYzMGYxZGRlY2Y1Zjg5MDMzZTI2YjYzMTcxNjcwMzE5OTgiLCJpYXQiOjE1MzIyNjA3ODUsIm5iZiI6MTUzMjI2MDc4NSwiZXhwIjoxNTYzNzk2Nzg1LCJzdWIiOiI1Iiwic2NvcGVzIjpbXX0.f_Xv0SrtTZ9m-40oHjAglCbKv76s_bARQ74XDihhFnI-jtHKwCWiF-jai5Yt6h9QyakCTZEo1bPAJdeph7Bj0_tKJpq3sGvK4t73_LZg_OOcsmAt61a4OSAgI1pjPV0tMMwHCoHm-xLlNnriAyaLCAbTQLQkfrw53467ys6rchE5V0rzy-JswjTfmB6SvZcqXsJQo6CWDRTWYbKvJO0FSmdZfLxxO_u4i_8ah5W63qJ4MSN9q22zkZLQ-L3NZhOux2KkwWiySioL2K25Y_UZmefClYwk1h-EY_LEVht3U7Kpqn9fmM6_Q4ByD-sSzLdAixdbq4REqinSaayzfMY934nijLu7ysEIc0oIukiHYcIk9tGV6DNuQ0CWhqEn0W_308MSBU4Ffyi5SQo7ubb5uPG7l_XOdomIR9dK9KtVONbPe7iF6TuccPCWZwvqKgfFl7TqEgiUWSiAl_ekkiaUDEM3cIuIH8AOLE17UuW4W0VyR2ziIt68au8SEuP2ilMBRsRMsFGbRKQWcvLluNw_qubcdzZ4yX9kuQAvXuBrHAcXb9WMlki2votvd7RKVDwxqwsTJRoeKNtJQdEQRbRZUD6nXyzGkmtEMrfwYoLVgTX3vAgVjO_erYtI5x-NV-EnoLT352odtRDYh5gTzVbmzYAxbLf_XUCDHjvlMEvM81g",
    "status": true,
    "status_code": 1,
    "message": "Login successfully."
}
```

I want to add business types details too, so can you please guide me how to add relation for that table.

Thanks.

Comment: do you have `UserBusiness` model ?

Comment: @rkj Yes. I have created models for each table. I have updated my question.

Comment: i have added answer check it

Comment: your User model relation with business is fine, just add one relation in UsersBusiness and you are done

Comment: why have you added `user_id` in userbusiness table  and `business_id` in user table ? i think you don't need `business_id` in users table. Just keep `user_id` in userbusiness table and then add either 'hasOne` or `hasMany` relation in User model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a belongsTo relation in your `UserBusiness` model like this

**UserBusiness Model**

```
public function businessType(){
     return $this->belongsTo(BusinessType::class, 'business_type_id');
}
```

After that load it like this

```
$user = Auth::user();
$user->load(['usersBusiness.businessType']); //lazy loading
dd($user);
```

if you want userBusiness and their type only then

```
dd($user->usersBusiness);
```

**Side Note:**  i think you don't need `business_id` in users table. Just keep `user_id` in userbusiness table and then add either `hasOne` ( if user can have only one business) or `hasMany` (if user can have more than one business) relation in User model for userBusness.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use [API Resources.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-resources)

For example, in my case I have **ChannelItemResource.php**:

```
public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
    'id' => $this->id,
    'channel_id' => $this->channel_id,
    'channel' => $this->channel->title,
    'type' => $this->type,
    'description' => $this->description,
    'price' => $this->price,
    'created_at' => $this->created_at,
    'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
];
    }
```

and **ChannelResource.php**:

```
return [
    'id' => $this->id,
    'title' => $this->title,
    'user_id' => $this->user_id,
    'description' => $this->description,
    'type' => $this->type,
    'url' => $this->url,
    'ranking_total' => $this->ranking_total,
    'ranking_flag' => $this->ranking_flag,
    'ranking_country' => $this->ranking_country,
    'thumbnail' => $this->thumbnail,
    'state' => $this->state,
    'hit' => $this->hit,
    'created_at' => $this->created_at,
    'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
    'items' => ChannelItemResource::collection($this->items),
];
```

With this structure, you can easily include which relation you want and the result will be in JSON.

In **Controller** use:

```
public function all(Request $request)
    {
        return new ChannelsResource(Channel::where("state", "active")->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(30));
    }
```